# Rails engines testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-engines

We are using a rails engine that has to be able to access models and behavior from the containing application, but because we're testing in a dummy application we can't test with those things and end up mocking and stubbing the entire left half of the world out just to write simple tests.

Is there some way, via configuration, code or just ritual sacrifice of farm animal, that I can have our engine tests run in the context of the containing application rather than in the dummy test application?

Comment: I suppose it isn't feasible in this case to incorporate the target functionality (in a testable way) into the dummy app?

Comment: The challenge becomes making sure that the duplicated functionality is kept up to date. I'd just prefer to be able to refer to it directly. Actually, I'd prefer to do this an entirely different way.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach it differently

- Establish the interface the consuming application should observe. Then assume that a valid application always use your gem on the way it's supposed to
- Given the defined interface, any application using the gem should look the same from the gem standpoint. So having a mock application that sets up a example domain to be tested in the context of your gem becomes ok. Don't mock anything, create an application with actual models or any layer that is required to interact with your engine

If there's no way to define how it would ultimately be used, or you still want to enable consumers to test integration points, then provide test helpers. Something like [rack-rest](https://github.com/brynary/rack-test), that provides a test infrastructure for rack users.

Those can be required and used on whatever testing framework is being used by the app and can be used if deemed required.

Comment: Yeah. Honestly, given the requirements of this project I wouldn't use an engine in the first place, but the people calling the shots are insisting on this setup. And I don't want to be in the position of having to replicate the actual models in the engine/test space.

Comment: Can't you follow the last point and then create assertion methods that will allow testing to be written by the consumer app developers?